# errors in CUDA example

Tags: bugs, documentation, cudalink

It seems that there are some errors in the documentation page Consider these functions in the documentation [CUDA Programming](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Programming.html#171702432).
However, I'm not a expert in CUDA nor C, could you check whether these are indeed errors or I'm missing something?

**error 1**

> ```
> __global__ void addTwo_kernel(mint * arry, mint len) {
>
>     int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx * blockDim.x;
>
>     if (index >= len) return;
>
>     arry[index] += 2;
> }
> ```

Should `blockIdx` be `blockIdx.x` ?

**error 2**

> ```
> void xAverage_cpu (mint * in, mint * out, mint width, mint height, mint pitch) {
>       int xIndex, yIndex, idx;
>       mint left, curr, right;
>
>       for (yIndex = 0; yIndex < height; yIndex++) {
>             for (xIndex = 0; xIndex < width; xIndex++) {
>                   idx = x + y*pitch;
>
>                   left = idx > 0 ? in[idx - 1] : in[yIndex*pitch];
>                   curr = in[idx];
>                   right = idx < width - 1 ? in[idx + 1] : in[width + yIndex*pitch];
>
>                   out[x + y*pitch] = (left + curr + right)/3;
>               }
>         }
>   }
> ```

Should `x` and `y` be `xIndex` and `yIndex` instead ?

**error 3**

> ```
> void xAverage_cpu(mint * in, mint * out, mint width, mint height, mint pitch) {
>   mint accum;
>   mint left, curr, right;
>
>   for (yIndex = 0; yIndex < height; yIndex++) {
>       accum = 2*in[yIndex*pitch] + in[yIndex*pitch + 1]
>       out[yIndex*pitch] = accum/3;
>
>       accum -= in[yIndex*pitch];
>
>       for (xIndex = 0; xIndex < width-1; xIndex++) {
>           idx = x + y*pitch;
>
>           accum += in[index+1];
>           out[idx] = accum/3;
>           accum -= in[idx-1];
>       }
>       accum += in[width - 2 + yIndex*pitch];
>       out[width - 1 + yIndex*pitch] = accum/3;
>   }
> }
> ```

Should

1. `index` in `accum += in[index+1]` be `idx` instead?
2. a ";" is missing after `accum = 2*in[yIndex*pitch] + in[yIndex*pitch + 1]`?
3. the declarations for `xIndex`, `yIndex` and `idx` are missing?
4. `xIndex = 0` in  `for (xIndex = 0; xIndex < width-1; xIndex++)` should be `xIndex = 1`?

**error 4**

> ```
> __global__ void xAverage_improved_kernel(mint * in, mint * out, mint width, mint height, mint pitch) {
>   extern __shared__ smem[];
>
>   int tx = threadIdx.x, dx = blockDim.x;
>   int xIndex = dx*blockIdx.x + tx;
>   int yIndex = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
>   int index = xIndex + yIndex*pitch;
>
>   if (yIndex >= height) return;
>
>   smem[threadIdx.x+1] = index < width ? in[index] : in[yIndex*pitch + width - 1];
>
>   if (tx == 0) {
>       smem[0] = index > 0 ? in[index-1] : in[yIndex * pitch];
>       smem[dx+1] = index+bx < width ? in[index+dx] : in[yIndex*pitch + width - 1];
>   }
>
>   __syncthreads();
>
>   if (xIndex < width)
>       out[index] = (smem[tx] + smem[tx+1] + smem[tx+2])/3;
> }
> ```

Should

1. `bx` be `dx`?
2. `extern __shared__ mint smem[]` instead of `extern __shared__ smem[]`?

Comment: I don't really have experience here, but it seems that might be the case when you compare yours with the similar example under the heading "Second Kernel" a little further down that page, in which you indeed have `blockIdx.x` in an identical construction as the one you shown above.

Comment: Are you able to test these code snippets in their original form and with your proposed changes? I don't have access to CUDA capable hardware.

Comment: @MarcoB I'm able to test some, but these errors are all basic compiling errors.

Comment: If you have confirmed these as errors, you might want to include that in your question. Additionally, I'm afraid that I don't see what your question is here. It might be more expedient to report these documentation problems to Wolfram Support instead.

Comment: @MarcoB I'm not a expert on CUDA, so additional check from others may be needed. I'll report to Wolfram support shortly. I post here just to keep it in the bug tracking list the community is maintaining.